# AntD Form - call onChange event manually

Tags: reactjs, antd

When I set the state of 2 dates fields programmatically, the `FormItem` property - `reuqired` doesn't allow pass me further:

```
<Form
form={props.form}
name="WorkersWorkerdForm"
onFinish={onFinish}
scrollToFirstError
autoComplete="off"

onValuesChange={formOnChangeHandler}
>
    <Form.Item name="start_date" rules={
        [
            {
                type: "object",
                required: true,
                message: "Required field!",
                whitespace: true,
            },
        ]}>
            <DatePicker
                selected={startDate}
                selectsStart
                startDate={startDate}
                onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
                //onSelect={f1GetStartDate}
                locale={ru}
                dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
                shouldCloseOnSelect={true}
                placeholderText="Select start date"/>
    </Form.Item>;
```

There is the handler for `onValuesChange`:

```
const formOnChangeHandler = (changedValues, allValues) => {
    setState(Object.assign({}, state, { ...allValues, }))
}
```

Now on the page I can see the fields are set with dates as following:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(getFirstMonthDate(new Date()));
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
```

But the dates fields still asking me for to set the field with mouse, showing that they are required due of the FormItem rule.

The question: How I can bypass this mechanic? I've tried to call them somewhere after useEffect on load, but this won't work:

```
useEffect(() => {
                    setState({  
                        department_id: 0,
                        start_date: startDate,
                        end_date: endDate
                    });
                }, []);
    
formOnChangeHandler(changedValues, allValues)...
```

I still need the date fields has to be required, same time when the state set programmatically on first page load, the form rules has to pass me further. Form is [AntD](https://ant.design/components/form).

Answer (score 0):

After digging in deep, I found that if we want to control form, then it should be defined first:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm()
```

and then it can be used to sync a states in my case:

```
form.setFieldsValue(state)
```